# AMQP over WebSocket with RabbitMQ

Tags: javascript, websocket, rabbitmq, amqp, sockjs

Is there a way to use AMQP to communicate with RabbitMQ over WebSockets?

I guess the real question is if there is support for this in RabbitMQ and if there are any client side libraries for the browser? Can not really wrap my mind around it and google provides no answers for me.

Today we are using the RabbitMQ STOMP-SockJS solution. But that does not work very well with LVC (Last Value Cache) and exchanges other than the default. Since it does not allow to bind multiple routing keys to the same queue. (It automatically creates a new queue for each subscription.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The best (most flexible, scalable, secure, etc) way to do this in my experience is to build a web server for your WebSockets and have the web server communicate with RabbitMQ.

Comment: This is the solution we ended up with.

Comment: Is there something already built that could be reused? I mean, something that proxies requests from WebSockets to RabbitMQ and back

Answer (score 0):

Kaazing has an AMQP JavaScript API that works with one of RabbitMQ's implementations of AMQP.  Its free for developers and can be downloaded [here](https://kaazing.com/download/#ee-kwg)

Full disclosure:  I work for Kaazing.

Comment: What does "free for developers" actually mean? The whole thing seems to have the Apache 2.0 license?

Comment: Very similar to other software offerings.  If you want to develop an application with the Kaazing AMQP software, there is no charge.  You can use the forums for support.  If you want to use it in production with 24/7 global support, there's a fee.  Pretty standard stuff.

Comment: Just to clarify.  Of course you're free to use the OSS version in Github in whatever way you want.  My comments were strictly about for-fee 24x7 support.